# Is it possible to populate a set of custom fields with data from a postcode dataset?

Tags: custom-fields

My organisation (and others I presume) would find it useful to populate a set of custom fields based upon a contact's postal code.

The dataset is the Scottish Index of Multiple Deprivation (SIMD), which provides demographic information by postal code area. The data is available as a CSV file: http://www.gov.scot/Topics/Statistics/SIMD/SIMDPostcodeLookup

What would be the best way of implementing this?

Comment: Have you had any progress with this? It's something we're interested in but haven't had a chance to explore, and it would be great to pool resources if possible!

Comment: Not yet sorry! It's been fairly low-priority for us, but if we get the funding to go ahead with it, I'll be happy to share.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension that provides this functionality called "[CiviCRM Region Lookup](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-region-lookup)".  It says it only works through CiviCRM 4.4; I'm not sure if anyone's tested it with a newer version, it might just work.

Note that it's not an easy process to set up for the very first time - but it's easier than writing custom code to handle this from scratch.  You may have follow-up questions, but that link should get you pointed in the right direction!